# Gitlab CI Pipeline with Token

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I created Personal Access Token in gitlab.com to read the gitlab api because I want to create some documentation about my repos in asciidoc automatically. Basically this works in a local script.

Now I want to turn this into a Giutlab CI pipeline. As of now the token is part of my local script. But I don't want this token to be readable in a public repo. Is there a way to get the token from the pipeline in a secure way without putting it into the .gitlab-ci.yml in plain text or any other reusable form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in your gitlab project `Settings > CI / CD > Variables`

There you can add Key value pairs which can be "masked" so aren't visible in scripts.

But you should be aware this isn't fully "secure" take a look [at this](http://gitlab.eb.local/help/ci/variables/README#security)